# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin. in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

When I am Running Command : ionic cordova run android

Error :Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin

I thing it is a Fcm Plugin problem

Kindly Solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

in Ionic 3

Update file from plateform -> android -> project-properties

> target=android-27 android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
>   android.library.reference.2=app
>
> cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
>   cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
>   cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0
>   cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+
>   cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+
>   cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/app-FCMPlugin.gradle
>   ***cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.+
>   cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.+***
>   cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+

and build it once again for android

enter code here

it working for me